# Tomcat server won't start if WEB-INF/classes directory exists

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am currently working on a Dynamic Web Project for school and I am running into a weird problem... I am trying to run a servlet from a .jsp file. I did a lot of research and apparently (please correct me if I'm wrong!) you need to place the compiled servlet or java class files into WEB-INF/classes directory if you want to use them within the .jsp file.

Before setting the build path to be this directory or even creating the directory, I was able to run my web app. The second I made the change to the build path, my server refused to start and I am now getting this error:

```
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/PullUp]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/PullUp]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [ListingServlet] and [com.pullup.ListingServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/ListingServlet] which is not permitted
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:316)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2384)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2066)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1951)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1945)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1945)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1156)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 6 more
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have both a `web.xml` file defining a servlet named `ListingServlet` and also a class named `com.pullup.ListingServlet` with a `@WebServlet` annotation?

Comment: Yes to both of those.

Comment: Annotations are an alternative to `web.xml`. You double-defined it, which is what the error is telling you. Don't do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting **both mapped to the url-pattern** exception because when Tomcat is trying to load the servlet classes, it has found 2 mappings for the same servlet i.e., one from `web.xml` and another from `@webservlet`.

`@webservlet` is an alternative way (in JavaEE6 containers) to define the servlet url mapping (inline to the servlet source code). So you should NOT add those servlets and mapping into the `web.xml` (i.e., just remove the web.xml from WEB-INF folder).

Comment: Thank you!! Was stuck on this for a very long time but this small adjustment fixed it! Thank you once again :)